# spring batch : Read Twice one after other from database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I need to know what is best approach to read the data from one database in chunk(100) and on the basis of that data we read the data from other database server . 
example : taking id from one database server and on the basis of that id we take data from other database server.

I have searched on google but have'nt got solution to read twice and write once in batch.

One approach is read in chunk and inside process we take id and hit the database. But process will take single data at a time which is most time consuming.

Second approach is make two different step but in this we can't able share list of id to other step because we can share only small amount of data to other step.

Need to know what is best approach to read twice one after other.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best approach as it depends on the use case.

> One approach is read in chunk and inside process we take id and hit the database. But process will take single data at a time which is most time consuming.

This approach is a common pattern called the "Driving Query Pattern" explained in detail in the [Common Batch Patterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) section of the reference documentation. The idea is that the reader reads only IDs, and the processor enriches the item by querying the second server with additional data for that item. Of course this will generate a query for each item, but this what you want anyway, unless you want your second query to send the list of all IDs in the chunk. In this case, you can do it in `org.springframework.batch.core.ItemWriteListener#beforeWrite` where you get the list of all items to be written.

> Second approach is make two different step but in this we can't able share list of id to other step because we can share only small amount of data to other step.

Yes, sharing a lot of data via the execution context is not recommended as this execution context will be persisted between steps. So I think this is not a good option for you.

Hope this helps.